# ppGallery - JS Script for Hidding Images

Tags: javascript

I have this gallery that does not support multiple albums on the same page and I need help to hide the images of the second album that I created. How can I hide the four images below the images with the text?

I duplicated the JS file, button ID, so I can see multiple albums on the same page, I don't understand what I'm missing here.

http://www.piterpan.it/ppgallery/giugno.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can use display property of CSS;

```
 <img src="yourWebsiteAddress/ppgallery/img/13-03-17/aperitour-marzo-01_tb.jpg" 
 style="display: none;">
```

Or you can use jQuery selectors;

```
$("#gallery").hide(); 
$("#view2").hide();
```

For convenience you can define a class for those you want to hide and simply

```
$(".hiddenClass").hide();
```

Comment: And if I want to hide all the "set" of images included in "ul id="gallery">" or "<div id="view2" ?

Comment: I inserted "visibility:hidden;" in the ppgallery.css  

#gallery, #gallery ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;width:600px;
 visibility:hidden;
}

Comment: You can practice using your browser (firefox or chromium). Right click on inpect element and see result of styling. Cheers..